# Not getting notifications of a new answer posted on page

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, notifications

Usually I get a notification at the top when a new answer is posted to a question that I'm reading, but recently this has not been the case. This has happened several times and I've had to delete my answer because it was essentially the same as the one posted while I was typing my own. I just checked with a recent question and it happened again. Anyone else experiencing this or could this just be a problem at my end?

The browser I'm using is Opera.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a test using Opera and received the following while posting a new answer.  If you can give me specific repro steps I'm happy to try them.

[image]