# The feature that gives notifications of new questions, new answers, new comments is not working

Tags: discussion, bug, notifications

I noticed that the feature that gives notifications of new questions, new answers, new comments is not working in my computer. Can you suggest how I can start getting those notifications again?

Has something been accidentally toggled off?? Please help.

I checked [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4275/not-getting-notifications-of-a-new-answer-posted-on-page) but it did not provide any remedy to my problem.

Comment: Websocket problems? New browser, new proxy settings, firewall?

Comment: Nope. I have been using these settings for over $3$ months.

Comment: Still, occasionally a websocket enters the eternal hunting grounds. When that happens, usually reloading the page helps (not always on the first try). Have you tried that?

Comment: On reloading the page, the new questions and answers appear. But the notifications don't.

Comment: Are you using browser extensions like Ghostery, NoScript or uMatrix? The path for notifications may have been rerouted causing whitelists to fail.

Comment: No, nothing like that. But onething I would like to add. My web connection is creating some disruptions since morning. Is it some how linked?

Comment: A flaky internet connection has a tendency to make websockets die. Could well be that.

Comment: I log in using Google's OpenId service.  Notifications are (of course) broken if the StackExchange servers don't recognize that one is logged in, and a clue in this circumstance is that the default user page will put focus on the Profile tab, rather than the Activity tab.